# what'is the difference between sprite kit and core animation

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit

I want to make a poker game. Accordnig to the user interface , i consider using coreanimation + native uiviewcontroller. My colleague recommand using sprite kit.
After reading sprite kit tutorial， i can't find the advantage of sprite. Most of the animation can be finished by core animation. So can anyone explain what's the difference between them.
Thank you!

Comment: Your question would be better suited for the Game Development Stack Exchange. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

core graphics is more general purpose i heard in gaming. but if you want to build a high performance game then spritekit because it is built on top of metal (in WWDC 2022 apple release new Metal 3 which is faster).

Comment: my bad its core animation. core animation is easier if you just want to animate movement like poker game. but learning spritekit are better if you want to take game dev career in apple

Comment: Thanks. I just want to discuss core animation and sprite for building poker game or mahjong game.

Answer (score 0):

Compare to core animation it is far easier to use animations and actions in sprite kit.

Also sprite kit has batter performance for many many animations happening simultaneously, core animation could be good option for games like 2048 which uses few animations i think.

i have created this ludo like game in sprite kit : https://appadvice.com/app/parchis-star-real-ludo/1495213569